# how to get basic line highchart dynamically through json data

Tags: javascript, json, graph, charts, highcharts

my json data is :

```
{"09/02/2014 15:36:25":[33.82,33.42,40.83],"08/11/2014 16:25:15":[36.6,33.42,40.45],"07/30/2014 08:43:57":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"08/12/2014 22:00:52":[77.99,74.1,80.12],"08/12/2014 21:19:48":[56.91,63.23,52.42],"07/23/2014 13:37:46":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"08/11/2014 17:35:21":[40.9,43.83,38.34]}
```

I want this data into high chart basic line graph i want date in x-axis and data in y axis.
ex: date is for x-axis : 09/02/2014 15:36:25
data is for y axis : 33.82,33.42,40.83 (for three different line say data1,data2,data3)

for manually generated graph i was using : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

how to get dynamically generated graph from above json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first of all get the values from your JSON data like:

```
Object.keys(data); //this will return dates
data[xAxis[0]]; //this gives the values corresponding to each date (currently first date)
```

then you need to populate the chart with these values dynamically:

```
var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
for(var i=0; i<xAxis.length; i++) {
    chart.addSeries({
        name: xAxis[i],
        data: data[xAxis[i]]
    });
}
```

and btw you can't show the dates on xAxis because each data value have 3 points but x axis categories if you put the date their will be more than that. the logical representation would be showing each date as separate series like i did in my example.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzvhzm94/)**